# Get CMS page title using url-key

Tags: cms

Below is my code to get CMS page title using CMS page url-key (identifer)

```
$formatIdentifier = "'{$_product->getUrlKey()}'";
$PageData = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($formatIdentifier,'identifier');
echo print_r($BuyingTitle->getData());exit;
```

The above code returns null, while the below code returns expected data.

```
$PageData = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load('my-identifier','identifier');
echo print_r($BuyingTitle->getData());exit;
```

How can I pass my dynamic identifier using variable to get CMS page data ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are adding quotes that are probably messing it up

```
$PageData = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->load($_product->getUrlKey(),'identifier');
echo print_r($BuyingTitle->getData());exit;
```

should work

Comment: Will this work ? 

$BuyingTitle = Mage::getModel('cms/page')->getResource()->getCmsPageTitleByIdentifier($_product->getUrlKey());

Comment: I didn't test it but `Mage::getResourceModel('cms/page')->getCmsPageTitleByIdentifier($_product‌​->getUrlKey());` should basically work

Comment: I do not know why my code did not work at first. I then tried for quotes.Thanks...:)